# How to modify columns from data frame using function like excel?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I want to change 'c' column of data frame using below conditions.
condition:
When components of 'c' divided by 8, if remainder is larger than 4, change 'the components+1'
,else change 'the components+5'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[4,5,6,7],'c':['1','2','3','6']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

result I want to obtain is like that..

```
A = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[4,5,6,7],'c':['6','7','8','7']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert to integer using **[`series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)**, then use **[`series.mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html)** and use **[`series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)** to compare greater than 4, finally use **[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)**

```
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(int)
c = df['c'].mod(8).gt(4)
df['c'] = np.where(c,df['c']+1,df['c']+5)
```

---

```
print(df)

   a  b  c
0  1  4  6
1  2  5  7
2  3  6  8
3  4  7  7
```